# How to keep updating value of a variable by clicking on a button in JavaScript after it was entered in INPUT first?

Tags: javascript

I'm a rookie JS programmer making first steps into programming, so I appreciate your help to help me learn it.

I have created a function that adds 5 to a value entered by the user in INPUT. The result is displayed in . It works perfectly. After clicking the button the result shows up. However, I want to use the same button to keep adding another 5 to the output value without entering a new value in the INPUT.

I've tried:
-declaring the undefined value (let sum; )outside the function to make the variable global but it didn't work.

I was thinking about:

- storing the value in an empty array but I don't know how to access it with my button (I don't think it's the right way)
- removing the eventListener from the button and creating another function to keep adding 5 by clicking (a not changing the input value).

```js
let sum;
let sum2;

function adder5() {
  let userNumber = Number(document.querySelector("#yourNumber").value);
  sum = userNumber + 5;
  document.querySelector("#output").textContent = sum;
}

document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", adder5);

function adderContinue(sum) {
  document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", function () {
    sum2 = sum + 5;
  });
  document.querySelector("#output").textContent = sum2;
}
```

```html
<input id="yourNumber" type="number" />
<button id="btn">Calculate</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```

I appreciate your help. Any hint will do because I'm stuck. BTW I realize that variable SUM changes into SUM2 after the first click event, but the code should work at least once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the input field's event to update the cached value and update it on button click.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input'),
  button = document.getElementById('button'),
  output = document.getElementById('output');
let value = input.valueAsNumber;

input.oninput = function () {
  value = this.valueAsNumber;
};

button.onclick = function () {
  value += 5;
  output.textContent = isNaN(value) ? '' : value;
};
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input" />
<button id="button">Calculate</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks Shreevardhan. It WORKS. I just wanna ask about your code: input.oninput = function () {
  value = this.valueAsNumber;
};  Is this the same as Number(value)? It only changes the input from a string into a number?

Comment: It represents the value of the input field, interpreted as a Number, go through the W3C draft for more details https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-input-element-attributes.html#dom-input-valueasnumber

Comment: Last question: You used "button" and "output" without any "var","let", "const". How is that possible that it works? Sorry, I'm a newcomer to JS.

Comment: The `const` in the first line is doing the job. You can declare multiple variables in the same expression, separated by comma

Answer (score 0):

- You may create a variable to store old user input and check if it is equivalent to the new user input or not.
- If it is equal then only add 5 to the sum
- Else add the user input with 5

```js
let sum = 0;
let oldUserInput = 0;

function adder5() {
  let currentUserInput = Number(document.querySelector("#yourNumber").value);
  
  if(currentUserInput === oldUserInput){
    sum = sum + 5;
  } else {
    sum = currentUserInput + 5;
    // Update the oldUserInput to the current
    oldUserInput = currentUserInput;
  }
  document.querySelector("#output").textContent = sum;
}

document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", adder5);
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate but it doesn't work and I means something different. When I don't enter the value in INPUT, it's somehow treated as "0" already. After I click it adds 5 (the result is "5").  HOWEVER, I want to add another 5 to the first output value after I click on the button. ==>1. First I enter the number and click. (I get the sum). 2. I click again and the result should be the first SUM + 5. (Is it possible to keep adding by just clicking on the button?)

Comment: That is what is happening. If you click the button again and again, it will add 5 to the sum. But i see, when there is no value, you want the button to do nothing ?